# qemu: Unsupported syscall when Docker build

Tags: docker, .net-core, qemu

I'm trying to build a docker container in Visual Studio Code (I'm actually working with IoT Edge modules). The application is the OPC Publisher module for IoT Edge that you can find [here](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-opc-publisher/). I'm working on Windows 10

I have the following Dockerfile:

```sh
ARG runtime_base_tag=2.1-runtime-bionic-arm32v7
ARG build_base_tag=2.1-sdk-bionic-arm32v7

FROM microsoft/dotnet:${build_base_tag} AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./src/*.csproj ./opcpublisher/
WORKDIR /app/opcpublisher
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/. ./opcpublisher/
WORKDIR /app/opcpublisher
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# start it up
FROM microsoft/dotnet:${runtime_base_tag} AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/opcpublisher/out ./
WORKDIR /appdata
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/opcpublisher.dll"]
```

When I run the command `docker build` I have the following error:

```
Step 7/16 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in d6bd61466c67
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 389
```

And then it's waiting indefinitely, the process is not exiting with error code or something else.

It seems to be an error with the .NET command. I commented the step 7 in the Dockerfile and I got the same error at the step `RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out`

I installed qemu and [.NET cli tools](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install) (this ?) but I still have the error.

Does someone have an idea of the problem ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

When I run VS code as asdministrator, I have this additional output:

```
Step 7/16 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 293e6271cb65
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 389
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 139
```

And the command stops (no more indefinitely wait)